# Getting "Failed to build synonyms" message when trying to build synonyms filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch 6.8 with python 3.7

I'm trying to create my own synonyms which refer to emoticons as text.
for example: ":-)" will refer as "happy-smiley".

I'm trying to build and create the synonyms and index with the following code:

```
def create_analyzer(es_api, index_name, doc_type):
    body = {
        "settings": {
                "index": {
                    "analysis": {
                        "filter": {
                            "synonym_filter": {
                                "type": "synonym",
                                "synonyms": [
                                    ":-), happy-smiley",
                                    ":-(, sad-smiley"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "analyzer": {
                            "synonym_analyzer": {
                                "tokenizer": "standard",
                                "filter": ["lowercase", "synonym_filter"]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
        "mappings": {
            doc_type: {
                "properties": {
                    "tweet": {"type": "text", "fielddata": "true"},
                    "existence": {"type": "text"},
                    "confidence": {"type": "float"}
                }
            }}
    }
    res = es_api.indices.create(index=index_name, body=body)
```

But I'm getting errors:

```
lasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', 'failed to build synonyms')
```

What is wrong and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can say you whats wrong, (updated) how to fix this.

So if you will run this query in dev tools or bu cURL you will see the reason of error - think that Python cutting error details, so you cannot see reason.

```
PUT st_t3
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "synonym_filter": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms": [
              ":-), happy-smiley",
              ":-(, sad-smiley"
            ]
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "synonym_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "synonym_filter"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "tweet": {
        "type": "text",
        "fielddata": "true"
      },
      "existence": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "confidence": {
        "type": "float"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "remote_transport_exception",
        "reason": "[127.0.0.1:9301][indices:admin/create]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "failed to build synonyms",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "parse_exception",
      "reason": "parse_exception: Invalid synonym rule at line 1",
      "caused_by": {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "term: :-) was completely eliminated by analyzer"
      }
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

So the reason `"reason": "term: :-) was completely eliminated by analyzer"` - means that Elastic not supporting this characters in synonym filter.

**UPDATE**

It can be done by `char_filter` filter.

Example:

```
PUT st_t3
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "char_filter": {
          "happy_filter": {
            "type": "mapping",
            "mappings": [
              ":-) => happy-smiley",
              ":-( => sad-smiley"
            ]
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "smile_analyzer": {
            "type": "custom",
            "char_filter": [
              "happy_filter"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "tweet": {
        "type": "text",
        "fielddata": "true"
      },
      "existence": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "confidence": {
        "type": "float"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Test

```
POST st_t3/_analyze
{
  "text": ":-) test",
  "analyzer": "smile_analyzer"
}
```

Answer

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "happy",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 2,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "smiley",
      "start_offset" : 2,
      "end_offset" : 3,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "test",
      "start_offset" : 4,
      "end_offset" : 8,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 2
    }
  ]
}
```